# Google Charts API value misaligned

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using the Google Chart API to display some game outcomes, however, the highest value always shows up aligned to the edge within the green bar instead of above the bar (or at least with some padding between the top and the text).

I use the following URL to generate the chart:

[http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chd=t:14.1,2.1&chp=1.57079633&chs=300x155&chl=|&chco=43A443|D53030|3B74CA|FFDC00&chf=bg,s,00000000&chbh=70&chds=0,14&chm=N*0,FFFFFF,0,-1,20,,ve::15&chp=10][1]

This generates a chart that looks like the following (I need 2 more rep on SO to post images, can someone please edit to include this image?):

```
![http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chd=t:14.1,2.1&chp=1.57079633&chs=300x155&chl=|&chco=43A443|D53030|3B74CA|FFDC00&chf=bg,s,00000000&chbh=70&chds=0,14&chm=N*0,FFFFFF,0,-1,20,,ve::15&chp=10][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiE2d.png
```

There is actually a 2 above the red bar that is aligned correctly, but since the background on SO is white, it's not showing up.

How can I make it appear ABOVE the green bar. I've torn the API a part and tried seemingly every combination with no avail.

The API reference is available here: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with "chm".

I removed the color specifications, and now the link works perfectly.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chd=t:14.1,2.1&chp=1.57079633&chs=300x155&chl=|&chco=43A443|D53030|3B74CA|FFDC00&chf=bg,s,00000000&chbh=70&chds=0,14&chp=10&chm=N,,0,-1,20,,ve::15